# Is it possible for a physics major to get admission in a vet school?

Tags: veterinarian

I am currently doing my master's in Physics and my research focuses on machine learning to identify novel genetic modifiers of a mutant protein (slowly trying to move to biology!). I really want to be a vet and I am trying to figure out the pros and cons. I hope I will be able to support my studies with three years of data science training. Is this a good plan? I would be really appreciate it if there is any suggestions for me.

**Edit**: I understand that vets require a professional certificate and/or licensure in the country they want to practice. I am primarily interested to know about the scope of making the switch in career-paths in the US or Germany. But I would love hear about it with respect to any country.

Comment: I'm not completely sure if this is off or on topic. It's not really about pets (more about careers), so it may be off-topic.

Comment: @Nai54, My question was closed in academia stack exchange. So I made a few edits and directed my question to vet professionals. Where can I ask this?

Comment: I don't know. I would wait and see what the rest of the Pets SE community thinks before deleting or reposting it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes – having a more uncommon major may help your application stand out among all the biology or animal science majors. It may obviously vary somewhat depending on the exact school you apply to.

The main thing is making sure you have completed all the required biology-related pre-requisites, have good marks, and have plenty of work experience in the veterinary field. I would say that data science training, while a great supplement to your application, is not a substitute for veterinary experience.

To discuss more specifics of your application with other current and former students I would suggest taking a look at the [Student Doctor Network Veterinary Forums](https://forums.studentdoctor.net/categories/veterinary-forums-dvm.163/).